# Repeat labels in each x position on polar graph

Tags: highcharts, polar-coordinates

I need to repeatedly display the labels for each x axis on polar graph (via highcharts). Currently I have that (via [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6upMk/)):

```
jQuery("#container").highcharts({

    "chart": {
        "polar": true,
        "type": "line"
    },

    "title": {
        "text": "VIDA PESSOAL"          },

    "legend": {
        "enabled": false
    },

    "pane": {
        "size": "80%"
    },

    "xAxis": {
        "categories": ["fam\u00edlia\/amigos","moradia","sa\u00fade","dinheiro",
                       "crescimento pessoal","crescimento profissional","lazer"],
        "tickmarkPlacement": "on",
        "lineWidth": 0
    },

    "yAxis": {
        "tickInterval": 1,
        "min": 0,
        "max": 6
    },

    "plotOptions": {
        "line": {
            "lineWidth": 0
        },
        "series": {
            "animation": false,
            "color": "red"
        }
    },

    "series": [{
        "name": "Pontuação",
        "data": [2,1,5,3,1,3,3],
        "pointPlacement": 'on'
    }]

});
```

So I expect one of this results (see example images):

1. The labels "0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5" stay in ALL x lines - [**image**](http://bayimg.com/oAnCkAAfN).
2. Show label on top of each plot - [**image**](http://bayimg.com/oANCnaafn);
3. Show label inside each plot - [**image**](http://bayimg.com/OANCMaAFn);

The best solution is the first, but I can consider others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable datalabels, set color and adapt y parameter.

```
                marker:{
                    radius:10
                },
                dataLabels:{
                    enabled:true,
                    color: 'white',
                    y:7
                },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6upMk/3/